# All NSUserDefaults, all in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

Ok so I have a program where it saves the users preferences in their own key. So `forKey:textField.text`

So I really don't know what the user is using, they can make as many as they like, I want to be able to have a table view that can get all of the NSUserDefaults from the program, and display it.

Can I make an array with all of the NSUserDefaults? I know how to display an array.
This was SOLVED!

Ok so this is how I solved it, every time the user made new object, it saves to NSArray and that NSArray saved to NSUserDefaults. I have prepareForSegue which will give the information to the tableView, and it shows up. When cell is pressed it gets the cells name, and enters in `forKey` and then it works!

With some help from the answered question below!

Thanks for the people who took the time to answer!

Comment: Let me make a guess, do you want this for user settings?

Comment: No you didn't search everywhere. Like most of the questions around here, what you need is well written at the class reference document.

Comment: Have you worked through any online tutorials? SO isn't a code writing service, but you can add an NSArray (or NSMutableArray) to NSUserDefaults, so you can store all of your strings into an array and simply write/read the array to NSUserDefaults

Comment: class reference document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an array to userDefaults, the implementation is very simple.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self addTextToUserDefaults:@"hello"];
    [self addTextToUserDefaults:@"how are you?"];
    [self addTextToUserDefaults:@"hi"];

    for (NSString *text in [self textsInUserDefaults]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", text);
    }
}

- (void)addTextToUserDefaults:(NSString *)aText
{
    NSMutableArray *texts = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"textArray"] mutableCopy];
    if (!texts) {
        texts = [NSMutableArray new];
    }
    [texts addObject:aText];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:texts forKey:@"textArray"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

- (NSArray *)textsInUserDefaults
{
    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"textArray"];
}
```

So you can simply copy `addTextToUserDefaults` and `textsInUserDefaults` methods
Call `[self addTextToUserDefaults:textField.text];` to add text,
Call `[self textsInUserDefaults]` to retrieve the array of texts.